# Spinners & Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am working on an application which contains three `Fragments`

```
 [HeaderFragment] 

 [MainFragment] 

 [FooterFragment]
```

It is a pretty big application and the *MainFragment* will show more then 30 other `Fragments`. To create a dynamic flow, I introduced some shortcuts. These are 5 `ImageViews` in the *FooterFragment* that are mapped to a `Fragment` inside the *MainFragment*. Everything works fine and is build up pretty clean and straight forward.

**Problem**

I want the user to customize the shortcuts. On each `LongClick` of one of the shortcut-ImageViews, I want to show a `Spinner` which will pop out a list of available shortcuts. When I select an item, this one will be set.

**1)** I have never worked with a `Spinner` before. I know how it looks like and how to implement it. But I have some custom requirements: I don't want the `Spinner`-dropdownbox View. What I mean is, when I perform a `LongClick` on one of my shortcutimages, I want to popup the list which will show some stuff. Is this possible?

**2)** Because I am working with `Fragments`.. My action is handled in the footer. When the `Spinner`-list pops open, I want it to cover the whole screen. Possible?

Comment: From your description, looks like you need to do a custom popup window. Maybe a popup menu will also work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just want to start a normal `Dialog` with items added to them list:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, myOnClickListener)
```

This will result in: [image]

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

You might want to use:

```
builder.setView(myView)
```

To set your own `ListView` where you can control the look and feel of the list.